# REST API Call to OKTA with filter fail

Tags: api, rest, okta

I'm building an integration with OKTA using APEX.

One of the actions I need to call is: get all the users which has updated in the past hour.

I'm executing the following code and get an error: 400 Bad Request.

```
Datetime dt = Datetime.now().addHours(-1);
string st_str = dt.formatGMT('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss') + '.000Z';
endpoint = okta_base_url + '/api/v1/users?filter=lastUpdated gt "' + st_str +'"';  

system.debug('>>Sync_last_hour_users endpoint:' + endpoint);   
//https://dev.okta.com/api/v1/users?filter=lastUpdated gt "2018-07-26T08:00:46.000Z"

req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
req.setMethod('GET');
http_response = http.send(req);
```

in Postman this same call works perfectly, I guess the case is with the spaces after the 'filter'.
I also tried:

```
https://dev.okta.com/api/v1/users?filter=lastUpdated&gt&"2018-07-26T08:00:46.000Z"
https://dev.okta.com/api/v1/users?filter=lastUpdated+gt+"2018-07-26T08:00:46.000Z"
```

but no good news here.

OKTA API [documentation](https://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/users#list-users-with-a-filter)

Any idea?

Comment: As the documentation states, you need to replace spaces with `%20` and quotes with `%22`

Comment: Thank you @CharlesKoppelman - that truly was the case here!